# Visual Studio 2017 Designer 'Invalid Markup' error although code works

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, designer

I copied a project made in this Youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OwyNiLPDNw&t=3602s

However, the designer shows "Invalid Markup" although the code works perfectly and building is successful. (The guy in Youtube-video encounters same problem (in 59:43-59:56), but solves it somehow. I have still the same problem.)

The XAML gives a blue underline under: Source="{Binding, which shows error: The name "HeaderToImageConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:WpfTreeView". The program still runs fine, I just don't see the designer.

I have tried to tackle this problem by trying the following things:

1. Configurate between Debug/Release and x64/x84 platforms
2. Delete .bin .obj and .vs folders
3. Delete ShadowCache folder
4. Clean, Rebuild and Build solution multiple times
5. Reset Visual Studio settings and restart computer

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTreeView.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTreeView"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

        <TreeView x:Name="FolderView">
            <TreeView.Resources>

                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Width="20" Margin="3" 
                                        Source="{Binding
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}},
                                            Path=Tag,
                                            Converter={x:Static local:HeaderToImageConverter.Instance}}" />
                                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C# (HeaderToImageConverter class):

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace WpfTreeView
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a full path to a specific image type of a drive, folder or file
    /// </summary>
    [ValueConversion(typeof(string), targetType: typeof(BitmapImage))]
    public class HeaderToImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public static HeaderToImageConverter Instance = new HeaderToImageConverter();

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // Get the full path
            var path = (string)value;

            // If the path is null, ignore
            if (path == null)
                return null;

            // Get the name of the file/folder
            var name = MainWindow.GetFileFolderName(path);

            // By default, we presume an image
            var image = "Images/Checkmark.png";

            // If the name is blank, we presume it's a drive as we cannot have a blank file or folder name
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                image = "Images/Arrow.png";
            else if (new FileInfo(path).Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory))
                image = "Images/Checkmark.png";

            return new BitmapImage(new Uri($"pack://application:,,,/{image}"));
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I find `Converter={x:Static local:HeaderToImageConverter.Instance}}" />` an odd way of addressing the convertor. 
You could also add the convertor in your app.xaml like

```
<Application x:Class="WpfTreeView.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:wpftreeview="clr-namespace:WpfTreeView"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>


        <wpftreeview:HeaderToImageConverter  
            x:Key="HeaderToImageConverter "/>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Next, reference your converter with

```
Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}, Path=Tag, Converter={StaticResource HeaderToImageConverter}}" />
```

Edit:

Can you try adding the assembly to the namespace declaration?
`xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTreeView;assembly=MyAssembly`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your assistance! Unfortunately, the problem is still the same. The program works, but the designer won't. The location of the blue underline has changed the place to under: `<wpftreeview:HeaderToImageConverter` and gives the same error: The name "HeaderToImageConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:WpfTreeView".

Comment: Added something in my answer, see if that helps

Comment: No. I tried that earlier. The namespace doesn't recognize the class. I have read that there is a lot of things wrong with Visual Studio and this problem is one of them. The code didn't work two days ago, but suddenly started working out of blue without doing anything.

Comment: UPDATE. New computer, everything works. I didn't have admin rights with the last computer (work laptop), I think that is the main reason for many or all of my problems.